# is it possible to copy a sqlite database to another location

Tags: android, sqlite

the device is not rooted. I am getting the following error when i try to copy the db:

java.io.FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)

I have the correct permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

here is my code:

```
source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
source.close();
destination.close();
```

is this even possible if the phone is not rooted?

Comment: that depends on where this database is. You can't copy files of other applications.

Comment: You can copy your app's database file to the External Storage. But then you have to write another app which takes it from  there. Or you can simply expose its data through a ContentProvider. [See](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/seamlessness.html)

Comment: How, exactly, are you defining the values of `currentDB` and `backupDB`?

Comment: currentDB is going to be the is defined as: /data/data/{package name}/databases/test.db      and backupDB is defined as: sdCard.getAbsolutePath() +"/database_Backups/